# Why don't the records navigate to the next record in textbox using sqldatareader

Tags: c#

I want records navigate to the next record in the textboxes using sqldatareader on the click event of the command button. However, for the code given below instead of moving and showing the next record, only the last record is being shown. Please suggest how to move to next records until the file reaches the end. Thank you.

```
private void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from stu", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr["st_id"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = (dr["st_name"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = dr["st_age"].ToString();
        }          
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: There are a couple of things you need to consider here.

Should you wish to view the next items the moment you click next, you'll need to change your code a bit.

This is a bit of a bad practise, but for your purpose:

You need to keep the connection open to start off with.
Then you'll need to NOT use the while. The while is where your problem is. The while will go to the end of your stream, and only show the last item.

SO:
My suggestion would be:
on button 1, open the connection, create your command and get your reader
on the "next" button, do a single read
Close on last button

Comment: I honestly prefer to rather read ALL the information into a list of objects, and then iterate through them 1 by 1